# How to fit URI image into ImageView depending on its width or height

Tags: java, android, image, imageview

I have an `ImageView` that's supposed to be as wide as its parent and have a max. height of `400dp` (the image could be shorter than that):

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/activity_write_post_attached_image_iv"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    card_view:layout_constraintHeight_max="400dp"
    card_view:layout_constrainedHeight="true"
    card_view:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    card_view:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    card_view:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"/>
```

So one thing is constant, I need the image to either fit or crop into the ImageView without any vertical or horizontal letterboxes. I also want the image to crop out any part larger than `400dp` in height, if the image is larger than that.

None of the scale-type options are giving me the desired output for all cases (e.g `fitXY` stretches the image and I can't do that), and I can't wrap my head around how to achieve this programatically. Any ideas?

Comment: Have you tried using centerCrop?

Comment: Yes. As I mentioned, I've tried all scale-types.